# Connectedness of graph of f

Tags: connectedness, path-connected

Prove that graph of a continuous function from a connected metric space M into the metric space N is a connected set.

I have absolutely no idea how to go about this question. Initially what I thought was to approach using contradiction but I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: It is the image of a  conneceted space under a continuous function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Should I go about the composition of functions? Like take g: graph(f)->N?

Comment: $x \to (x,f(x))$ is also continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: since you say contradiction, here is how i would do it: if the graph of f isn’t continuous, then there is a non-constant, continuous map from the graph of f to the set containing zero and one. pre-compose this with the map which takes x in M to (x,f(x)) to get a continuous, non-constant map from M to the set containing zero and one. this is a contradiction.